# Get a list of #define variables

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

Even though it should be impossible due to `#define` being a pre-processor directive I'd like to ask:

Is it possible to get a list of the `#define`'d variables within the actual program? Respectively, a list of conditional compilation symbols, defined within the project's properties.

**Why would I need that?**
I'm managing extensions by using symbols. I'm trying to get a List of them to add them in my about window like

```
Enabled Extensions:
CUSTOMER1_ABC_EXTENSION
CUSTOMER2_XYZ_EXTENSION
```

Without writing specific code for each extension.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You could examine the source file within the program.

Comment: Roslyn, being a Compiler-as-a-service, can do that. See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It's not related, I definatly just need a list of defined symbols to list as extensions without writing anything specific for each symbol. @ Asad, there is no code yet, see first sentence for description. @ haim770 thanks, it's as helpful as a link to google.

Comment: @SlapY, You're asking an abstract question, you're getting an abstract answer. If you want more concrete solutions, provide more context.

Comment: In the end, what is it that you're going to diagnose in the "About Window"? The generated assembly or the original source code?

Comment: What's so abstract about "How to get a list of #define symbols". See my edit above for context.

Comment: @haim770 and @ Sinatr The generated assembly. I'm dealing with software that needs about two hours to be tested to ensure that specific extensions are enabled. So I'd like to see which extensions are enabled at which customer version etc..

Comment: @SlapY, It *is* abstract when you don't specify *when* exactly you need that list (during compilation? runtime?). Your edit did specify that.

Comment: Is it really going to be the best way to support multiple customers that you have to perform separate compilation for each one? Can you not move features into separate assemblies/plugins and determine what features are available at application startup?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sadly, it is. At least for now. I just don't get the time to write a sophisticated system for managing this. I already started developing a plugin system that relies heavily on interceptions and reflection. But it's quite hard to deal with. The problem occures over three projects in my solution. One of which handles the database objects using dapper (ORM). Adding/removing properties of the object-classes also is kind of a deal-breaker. Why is this the case? Why do the customers have different database designs? Well, ask the 18 years old database design and its developer.

Comment: By the way, it's great how everybody tries to rip my logic apart and as soon as you guys get what I'm trying to do, everybody runs and nobody delivers.

Comment: @SlapY I don't understand what you mean by "there is no code yet". If you have a file within which you have the preprocessor directives, you have a source file. Could you explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: @Asad I did that because SO would only let me target one person. And the code is not really neccessary because it consists of #define CUSTOMER1_ABC_EXTENSION and #if CUSTOMER1_ABC_EXTENSION #endif - Basically what I'm trying to do within #if and #endif should be none of your concern and isn't relevant to the actual question I asked. I just wanted a solution to list the defined symbols and not a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using

```
public static class BuildVariables
{
    public static List<string> DefinedVariables = new List<string>()
    {
        #if CUSTOMER1_ABC_EXTENSION
        "CUSTOMER1_ABC_EXTENSION",
        #endif
        #if CUSTOMER2_XYZ_EXTENSION
        "CUSTOMER2_XYZ_EXTENSION",
        #endif
    };
}
```

Which is quite dirty and requires a change each time a new symbol is introduced. I don't like it.

Comment: @Sinatr It's dirty because it forces the developer to remember to put a new symbol to the list. It's not a problem to do it - it just s*cks. And no, I do not have an initializer code neither a lookup for the extensions. I would be happy, if you'd concider to stop assuming things you can not know. The extensions are rather inline than a seperate module or such. Why? As I described above, the classes that represent db tables are different for some customers. So I enable some of them by symbol. I know that THIS is the dirty part here but I do not get the time to fix it, as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the cannonical answer is that you cannot do it.  The MSDN documentation for [#define](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx) says:

> The scope of a symbol that was created by using #define is the file in which the symbol was defined.

This would suggest that you might be better off using reflection.  Maybe you could use an [Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx) class to decorate the extensions and provide run-time information that you can test for.

Comment: It's possible to set the symbols using project's settings (conditional build symbols).