# Get list of compiler #defined compiler variables in Fortran code, or from makefile?

Tags: compilation, fortran, gfortran

I think thatI basically have the same question as this one:

[Get a list of #define variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187434/get-a-list-of-define-variables)

but for Fortran, or (perhaps) a makefile. Is there any way of obtaining a list of #defined compiler flags/variables in Fortran? My hope would be to export the defined variables to a file in my simulation output folder. Specifically, I'm interested in the variables in my code that look like this:

```
 #ifdef _OPTIMIZE_ALGORITHM_
```

Also, if I cannot do this in Fortran code, can I do this somehow in my makefile? I'm using gfortran, hence the tag, but I'm not sure if that plays (or does not play) a critical role in this capability.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "gfortran -cpp -E -dM foo.f90" or "cpp -dM foo.f90" might help?

Comment: "gfortran -cpp -E -dM foo.f90" exports a file with a list! Can I control the output directory of that file?

Comment: There seems no option for specifying the output directory (as a gfortran option), but on Linux/Mac we can redirect the output to any specified file as "gfortran -cpp -E -dM foo.f90 > /some/work/dir/foo.log" etc.

Comment: Also, to remove a lot of macro definitions such as `#define __SIZEOF_INT__`, it may be useful to first generate a log file for an empty Fortran file (e.g., `gfortran -cpp -E -dM empty.f90 > empty.log`) and use the `diff` command to extract the meaningful lines, e.g. `diff empty.log foo.log | grep '#define'` etc.

Comment: Does it matter what the variables are set to?  The same variable could appear in both the #if and the #else part.

Comment: It would be a plus to know the value of the variables..